# Tables not creating? Syntax issue?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently doing a lab for school and cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting these errors (2 in particular). The first error thrown to me is that in the table "invoice" the PRIMARY KEY constraint is asking for a second right parentheses. The second error I'm receiving is in the creation of table "invprod" where it is arguing to me that "invno" doesn't actually exist.

I don't know if this is an error in my syntax or otherwise but any help is greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE invoice
(invno CHAR(5) NOT NULL
,invdate DATE
,orderno CHAR(5) NOT NULL
,CONSTRAINT invorder FOREIGN KEY (orderno)
          REFERENCES salesorder(orderno)
,CONSRAINT pkinvoice PRIMARY KEY (invno)
);

CREATE TABLE invprod
(invno CHAR(5) NOT NULL
,partno CHAR(4) NOT NULL
,shipqty INTEGER CHECK (shipqty>0)
,CONSTRAINT fk1invprod FOREIGN KEY(invno)
        REFERENCES invoice(invno)
,CONSTRAINT fk2invprod FOREIGN KEY(partno)
        REFERENCES part(partno)
);
```

Comment: You should use an editor with syntax highlighting.  The typo in the INVOICE table definition shows clearly in the post here because StackOverflow highlights keywords.  And once you can actually create the INVOICE table your second error will disappear as if by magic.

Answer (score 3):

You have typo `CONSRAINT` should be `CONSTRAINT`:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice
(
  invno CHAR(5) NOT NULL
,invdate DATE
,orderno CHAR(5) NOT NULL
,CONSTRAINT invorder FOREIGN KEY (orderno)
          REFERENCES salesorder(orderno)
,CONSTRAINT pkinvoice PRIMARY KEY (invno)
);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb396a/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Stupid mistake! Must be tired!

I'm still having issues with invprod not creating due to being unable to find invoice... I don't know if you see anything there as well,

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That fixed my first problem!

Comment: @kabloo12 First create tables part and sales order, then invoice and invprod at the end

Comment: @kabloo12 Please thank people by making their answer the Accepted Answer.